# Angular2 reactive form validate multiple email in single input field eg: cc in email form

Tags: angular, primeng, angular-reactive-forms

I am using Angular2 and primeng to build a simple email form with following fields:

```
To:
Cc:
Message:
```

Following is the snippet code from my component class:

```
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.createForm();
  }

  createForm() {
    this.requestForm = this.fb.group
    ({
      sendTo: ['', Validators.email],
      copyTo: ['', Validators.email],
      message: ['', Validators.required ]
    });
  }
```

And the html is:

```
<form [formGroup]="requestForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" class="ui-g">
  <div class="ui-g-12">
    <div class="ui-g" style="margin-top:30px;margin-bottom:10px;">
      <input formControlName="sendTo" pInputText placeholder="To:" class="ui-g-2">
    </div>
    <div class="ui-g" style="margin-top:30px;margin-bottom:10px;">
      <input formControlName="copyTo" pInputText placeholder="Cc:" class="ui-g-2">
    </div>
    <div class="ui-g" style="margin-top:30px;margin-bottom:10px;">
      <textarea formControlName="message" rows="5" pInputTextArea placeholder="Message" class="ui-g-8">
      </textarea>
    </div>     
    <div class="ui-g">
      <div class="ui-g-8">
        <button pButton type="button" label="Cancel" class="ui-button-secondary" (click)="onCancel()"></button> 
        <button pButton type="submit" [disabled]="requestForm.invalid" label="Submit" class="ui-button-secondary"></button>            
      </div>
    </div>           
  </div>
</form>
```

Here i want to validate whether the copyTo field is having valid emails. This is not single email field as CopyTo will have multiple emails with some separations.

Can anyone help me how to achieve this please?

Thanks

Comment: you need to write a custom validator for that. Just have to take the value from the input and split it on whatever is used to separate the emails and then validate each email. You can use the string method split which returns an array and for each array element perform the email validation. If one fails then you'd show an error message or something.

Comment: For a better user experience, you should replace your text input with [chips](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/chips). And it should be easier to validate each chip : you won't have to separate mails.

Comment: @Antikhippe thank you. May i know how to validate the email field using chips.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer to your last comment, here is how you can validate an emails field using chips.

First, create the `p-chips` element and add the `onAdd` event to check every time the user validate a chip :

```
<p-chips [(ngModel)]="emails" (onAdd)=testMail($event)></p-chips>
```

Then, in your component, declare the `testMail` function that will check if user input is a valid mail or not. If not, just remove last entry from `emails` array of strings :

```
testMail(event) {
  this.errorMessage = ''; // reinitialize error message

  if(!this.validateEmail(event.value)) {
    this.errorMessage = event.value + ' is not a valid mail address !'; // display message
    this.emails.pop(); // remove last entry from emails array of strings
  }
}
```

See [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/CKSQbSRBlORaYCcBNQ1r?p=preview)